# Is there a symbol for difference, like $\sum$ for summation?

Tags: summation, notation

Im curious, if there is a symbol for summation: $$\sum$$ 
then is there a symbol for difference? If not, if not how could I represent the difference of a sequence of numbers $(1-2-3-4-...)$?

Comment: You could write $1-\sum_{n=2}^k n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you're doing is adding a bunch of negative numbers to 1. $1 - 2 = 1 + (-2)$, $1 - 2 - 3 = 1 + (-2) + (-3)$, $1 - 2 - 3 - 4 = 1 + (-2) + (-3) + (-4)$, etc. So you can just use the summation operator. Say you want to take this to $-10$: $$1 + \sum_{i = 2}^{10} -i.$$

By the way, take a look at A034856 in Sloane's OEIS.

---

In calculus, there's this thing called "finite difference," defined by Mathworld as "the discrete analog of the derivative." This concept does have some bearing on what you're talking about, but is not exactly what you're asking. I thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: Or $$1-\sum_{i=2}^{10}i$$

Comment: @Stef That's cleaner, thanks

Answer (score 1):

$$a_1-a_2-\cdots - a_n= a_1-\sum_{k=2}^n a_k$$

Answer (score 1):

There is no symbol for difference, because difference is not *associative*.

If I have the four numbers $1, 2, 3, 4$, then adding them is unambiguous and will always result in $1+2+3+4 = 10$. It doesn't matter which order I add them in, I will always get the same result. This is because addition is *associative*: parentheses don't matter. For instance: $$1+(2+(3+4)) = (1+2)+(3+4) = (1 + (2 + 3)) + 4$$
So it is simple to have a symbol $\sum$ to just say "add all those numbers" without any more precision.

But what does "take the difference of all these numbers" mean? It could mean a variety of things, with a variety of different results. For instance:
\begin{align*}
((1 - 2) - 3) - 4 & = -8 \\
(1 - 2) - (3 - 4) & = 0 \\
(1 - (2 - 3)) - 4 & = -2 \\
1 - ((2 - 3) - 4) & = 6 \\
\end{align*}

So for this reason we don't have one symbol to say "take the difference of these numbers".

However, you can use symbol $\sum$ for a sum, and add minus signs yourself to explicitly signify which terms of the sum must be subtracted.